# Prediction Interval for Random Forest - large prediction dataset

Tags: r, random-forest

I have an RF model created using randomForest in R with 500 trees. I want to apply it to predict values for a large dataset (2 million rows) and get both the predicted value and prediction interval.

I found this code, which works for a subsample of the data:

```
pred.rf <- predict(fit2, newdat, predict.all=TRUE)
pred.rf.int <- t(apply( pred.rf$individual, 1, function(x){
                 c( mean(x) + c(-1.96,1.96)*sd(x), quantile(x, c(0.025,0.975)) )}))
```

The problem is that applying predict.all=TRUE to the full dataset makes the dataset to large to handle because I get the 500 individual trees for each row of data.

Is there a nice way to make this work? E.g. integrating the predict into the apply? I would rather not fit a new model using ranger or quantregForest.

Comment: Note that *this does not give you prediction intervals*, but *confidence intervals for the point prediction*: each tree gives you a point prediction for each individual, but disregards the residual variation. You then take quantiles of these point predictions, but that tells you how much the *point prediction* varies, not how much the *actual observable* will vary. [This may be helpful.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info) This is a common error, especially with random forests, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prediction-interval+random-forest.

Comment: (Also, unfortunately off-topic...)